# Integral Elements over Quaternion Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

If I consider the set $$\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{H})=\{a+ib+cj+dk : a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}$$ Then I was wondering what kind of elements are integral over $\mathbb{Z}$? I proceed as follows if x=a+bi+cj+dk, then $$(x-a)^2=(bi+cj+dk)(bi+cj+dk)$$ and hence $$x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=bc(ij+ji)+bd(ki+ik)+cd(jk+kj)=0$$ Hence it is integal, whenever we have $2a,a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, Is this correct?

Further
further, I can say that if the fractional part of $a,b,c$ and $d$ are denoted by $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$, then I must have that $2a \alpha, 2b\beta, 2c\gamma$ and $2d\delta$ are integers. Hence $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \in \{ 0,\frac12\}$ and hence by $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2+\delta^2 \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ and hence $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\delta \in \{0,\frac12\}$

Comment: there is an issue, it is possible $2a \alpha$ can be integer without $\alpha \in \{0,0.5\}$ and how this I sort this out?

Comment: You already concluded $2a \in \mathbb Z$, which means that the fractional part of $a$ can only be $0$ or $0.5$.

Comment: @Claudius, I wanted to know what about the fractional part of $b,c$ and $d$

Comment: The fractional part of $b$, $c$, $d$ need not be $0$ or $0.5$. For example, the element $x = \frac13\cdot (i + 2j + 2k)$ satisfies $x^2 + 1 = 0$. This also implies that the elements which are integral over $\mathbb Z$ are not closed under multiplication (e.g. $i$ and $x$ are integral over $\mathbb Z$ but not $ix$).

Comment: Okay, so the first example in the following link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_unique_factorization_domain doesn't give all the integral elements. It just says that integers, half-integer quaternion but they are not everything. Is it?

Comment: @Claudius,  It is actually easy for me to see that it is integral, but I am not sure how can I conclude that  $ix$ is not integral. That is because there might be a higher order monic polynomial which satisfies the element? The degree $2$ polynomial satisfying $ix$ is $9x^2+6x+9$ but there might be a higher order polynomial. or can I use that this polynomial is irreducible and any other polynomial satisfying $ix$ must divide this polynomial and hence its leading coefficent must be divisible by $9$ and hence cannot be $1$?

Comment: You can use [Gauß' Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomials)): every monic polynomial $P(X) \in \mathbb Z[X]$ satisfying $P(ix) = 0$ is divisible in $\mathbb Q[X]$ by $\mu(X) = 3X^2 + 2X+3$, say $P(X) = f(X) \mu(X)$ for some $f(X)\in \mathbb Q[X]$. By Gauß' Lemma, we actually have $f(X)\in \mathbb Z[X]$. But then the leading coefficient of $P(X)$ is divisible by $3$ contradicting the fact that $P(X)$ is monic. Hence $ix$ is not integral.